# Can't vertical center align text inside a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, text-alignment

`numBox` is a square `JLabel` like the ones in the game 2048. The text where the number goes will not vertically center.

neither

```
numBox.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
```

nor

```
numBox.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

are working.

Text shows up horizontally centered but at the top of the box that the label shows up in.
How do I get the text to show up in the middle of the JLabel?

Comment: `JLabel` is, by default, centered vertically, I would then assume that it's an issue with your layout

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). BTW - add a colored border to the label to see how big it is, @MadProgrammer is most probably correct as to why you do not see a change.

Comment: This is the exact behavior of adding the label to a panel with a default `FlowLayout`. Try a different layout manager. I won't suggest which one, because you have not provided enough context to make a good suggestion

Comment: When in doubt, add line borders of different color to everything to get the visual help on layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an alignment suggestion to the layout manager by using:

```
label.setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
```

If this doesn't help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.